# How to insert form data into database via restful api services and curl

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created restful api services and using cURL and postman I am able to insert, update, delete data. 
Now, I want to perform same operations dynamically using form view and not by postman extension.
Can anyone please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: You can write your **CURL** commands in your **PHP** code when the form is submitted or something like that. This link can help you [PHP API example](https://shareurcodes.com/blog/creating%20a%20simple%20rest%20api%20in%20php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call API using ajax. please check the example to understand easily and help you to implementation.[Codeigniter with rest API example] https://github.com/sachinbhosale1191/Assignment1